# Isoceles Triangle inscribed in Rectangle

Tags: plane-geometry

So I have rectangle $ABCD$ with isoceles triangle $EFC$ inscribed inside it.

[image: Isoscales triangle inscribed in rectangle]

I know the angle $\angle ECF$ and the length of $FB$ and $FC$. Is there some way to find $EA$ and $FA$? My intuition says yes, but after bashing at this problem for 30 minutes, I was still unable to find a solution. Is the problem soluble, and if so, what is the length of $EA$ and $FA$ in relation to angle $\angle ECF$, $FB$ and $FC$?

Note: I came across this problem when working on an implementation of is-point-inside-rectangle problem in CS. Being an active member of the Chem.SE, it seems that homework problems will be closed if I don't show an adequate amount of effort on the problem. If I need to edit the problem to include the work that I tried, please inform me.

Comment: Thanks @John Wayland Bales I'm not the best with images.

Comment: You're welcome. Thought it should look less square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $FB$ and $FC$ you can find $\angle BCF = \arcsin\left(\frac{FB}{FC}\right)$ , which added to $\angle ECF$ gives you $\angle BCE$.  Then, you can find $AB = FC \cdot\sin(\angle BCE)$ and $DE = FC \cdot\cos(\angle BCE)$.

Comment: Wow I feel so dumb now didnt see that focused too much on isoceles triangle. Thanks!

Comment: But why is $AB = FC * sin(\angle BCE)$ again?

Comment: There's a right triangle here, $CDE$.  Since $AB = DC$, $FC = EC$, and $\angle BCE = \angle DEC$, we can find $DC$ with $\sin$.

Comment: Ok thanks my brain didn't make the leap.